# how to include functions within all Silex routes DRY / global?

Tags: php, symfony, routes, silex

I want to include a file and a variable within all my routes e.g.

```
$app->get('/', function() use ($app) {

$auth='code';
require __DIR__.'/assets/helpers.php';

....

});

$app->get('login', function() use ($app) {

$auth='code';    
require __DIR__.'/assets/helpers.php';

....

});
```

I need to repeat the code on every route declaration. Putting the variable or redirect at the top of the file does not include it within the `$app` scope, even when setting `global $auth;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably best accomplished with [route middleware](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/middlewares.html#route-middlewares):

```
use Silex\Application;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$app = new Application();

$setup = function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    $auth='code';
    require __DIR__.'/assets/helpers.php';
};

$app->get('/', function() use ($app) {})
    ->before($setup);

$app->get('/login', function() use ($app) {})
    ->before($setup);
```

The only thing I am not sure of here is if this will cause scope issues for you. For example if you helpers depend on some other variable that might be established inside your controller closure then that might not work. But at that point I think it's kind of a bad smell in design and you should probably be abstracting those things into [Service Providers](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers.html).

Comment: Thank you. Took me a while to figure out I needed

'use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;'

at the top of the page to make this work

Comment: Yeah namespaces... sorry about that. Assumed you already had that set up in your file. I will add to my answer for others in the future.

Comment: Instead of adding the middleware in each of the routes, you can do it globally: ```$app->before($setup)```. Check [documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/middlewares.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

First of all - you'd better use composer autoloading instead of require/include, and refactor you helper functions into a class or multiple classes with explicit dependencies instead of using $auth variable defined outside of helpers.php

In a case you need some common code before **all** the routes - you can use `$app->before()` middleware, as mTorres mentioned.

When common code is needed before **some** of the routes - I use following approach:

```
use Silex\Application;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$app = new Application();

array_map(
    function($route) {
        $route->before(function(Request $request, Application $app){
            // common code goes here
        })
    },
    array (
        $app->get('/', function() use ($app) {}),
        $app->get('/login', function() use ($app) {})
    )
);
```

This approach also allows to avoid creation of global varible which holds  middleware callable (like e.g. `$setup` in example provided by prodigitalson).

Answer (score 0):

What I did was just define the functions inside a file named `helpers.php` and just `required` at the top of the controller.

Now I can just call any function inside any `route`, also just remember to make the functions as independent as possible, so as to not be dependent on any variable outside the scope.Anything that is needed can just be passed as parameters.

Also these are just plain good ol' functions, and not extended `Class` methods or anything else.